# angularjs +yii2 advanced translate

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, yii2-advanced-app, angular-translate

I have a angular frontend where my translateProvider look like this

```
app.config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider
  .useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: '../../common/messages/',
    suffix: '.json'
  })
 .preferredLanguage('en');
 $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');
}]);
```

when I create en.json folder inside common/messages everything is working fine. I am using i18n from yii2 which generate the file common/messages/en/yii.php. I want both frontend and backend to use same file when i try

```
app.config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider
  .useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: '../../common/messages/',
    suffix: 'yii.php'
  })
 .preferredLanguage('en');
 $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');
}]);
```

Is it possible to use php as suffix?
If yes, how can I use php suffix?

Thank You.